# word-wrapping on entire word and not on characters

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting text in my table to wrap the way I want. If a word doesn't fit on the rest of the line I want it to wrap on the entire word and put the whole word on the next line. Currently it looks like this: [image]

So in the example: "Vince" is broken up and nce" is put on the next line. In this situation I want it to put the whole word on the next line.

I've tried fiddling with the word-wrap and white-space properties, but the only way I can get it to not break in the middle of a word is by having it not wrap at all and the next goes off the side of the screen.

Is there a solution to this issue in HTML/CSS?

Comment: Is `word-wrap` defined somewhere else in the style sheet with a higher priority maybe? Have you tried by adding `!important`? Like this: `word-wrap: normal !important`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `word-wrap:normal;`

Example :

```css
.test {
  width: 11em;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
```

```html
<table class="test">
  <tr>
    <th>Col A
    </th>
    <th>Col B
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This paragraph contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.(Breaking words only at allowed break points)
    </td>
    <td>hello texthello texthello texthello text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "*The long word will break and wrap to the next line*" - not for me, in Chrome 50.0.2661.102/Windows 10 it doesn't; or did I misunderstand that sentence somehow?

Comment: @DavidThomas It would break words only at allowed break points & wrap to next line as required by OP.

Comment: I tried adding word-wrap: normal to my CSS but it makes no change to what I had in the picture. I even tried word-wrap: normal !important and still no change. I removed any other occurrence of the word-wrap attribute from the rest of my CSS to see if that would fix it, but no change.

Comment: Ahhh, I found a -ms-word-break from the template that was causing the issue. Thanks, this worked like a charm!

Comment: Good to know it helped :)